# Pass = in ajax url

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to use ajax on my page where I want to pass key value pair set via url.

```
xhttp.open("POST", "/ajax/myjsp.jsp?str=key1=value1|key2=value2" , true);
```

On doing request.getParameter("str") on myjsp.jsp it should give key1=value1|key2=value2.

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent` to make sure `=` is properly encoded as `%3D` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It worked as it is posted in my question.The error was it was not getting ajax file path.Just removed / in the beginning and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var uri = "/ajax/myjsp.jsp?str=key1=value1|key2=value2";
    var res = encodeURI(uri);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to encode a URI.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I realize OP has already commented that the issue was elsewhere, but for what it's worth, note that `encodeURI` doesn't encode any characters that are valid in an URI. So if the value of `str` contains an `&`, this will be allowed, and the server will treat that character as the end of `str`. Prefer something like: `var str = 'key1=value1|key2=value2; var uri = '/ajax/myjsp.jsp?str=' + encodeURIComponent(str);`